# How to fix background issue with cycles fog?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera, lighting, volumetrics, skybox

So, I used a cube to create the volumetric fog with volume scatter. The problem is that in the camera, the background is black instead of matching the fog. Is there any way to fix this? Is there something I missed?
[image]

Comment: Do you have your Film setting set to Transparent? I suspect it’s a problem with transparency. Disable Transparent and it should work as expected.

Comment: if Rich's comment does not help, please provide your blend file, because we cannot "smell" your settings and your provided info is not enough to be sure what the reason is....

Answer (score 1):

I just find out the solution, You have to go to your camera settings and set a bigger *Clipping End* value.